# How to retrieve a List from Firebase avoid asynchronous

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I know that when we retrieve data from Firebase ,it will be asynchronous, so ussally i will put all the code inside `addChildEventListener`, like example i want to sort `userList` below. But i am confused, if the List is really big, like million Users, so it means the method `sortUser(user)` will be called million times ? Can anyone explain this to me, I'm new to firebase

```
myRef.child("User").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            User user= dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            userList.add(user);
            sortUser(userList);
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: can you post what sortuser method does ?

Comment: It just compares user 's name

Comment: can you post that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently use a `ChildEventListener`, which means your `onChildAdded` gets called for each child node immediately and then later whenever a new child is added. This indeed can be a lot of invocations.

If you use a `ValueEventListener`, its `onDataChange` will only be called once for the initial data (no matter how many child nodes there are), and then once for each change.

By adding a `ValueEventListener` to your current set up, you can keep things simple: add the child nodes to the lit like you're already doing, but only sort in `onDataChange`.

```
myRef.child("User").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      sortUser(userList);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
};
```

Firebase will only synchronize the data for the `User` node once, even when you have two listeners on it.

Comment: Thank you, i got it

Answer (score 1):

You should probably retrieve the data sorted server side by using [order-by methods](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sort_data) and then listen to that one.

```
var userRef = firebase.database().ref('posts').orderByChild('Users');
```

If I guess correctly, you would not need separate sorting client side.

You can also filter data. Do refer the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data)

Comment: in my case i need to compare every user on server with the user login in my app :(